# SQL Regular Expression to find matching strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write an SQL Server query to find invalid data below is the regular expression which is working fine, but its not working fine with SQL Server query

**Regular Expressions**: ([0-9|a-zA-z]+[_|\d+]*.[a-zA-Z]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)

**SQL Server Query**:

```
select *
from table
where name like '([0-9|a-zA-z]+[_|\d+]*\.[a-zA-Z]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)'
```

**Sample Data Is**:

```
    efwfwf.wefwef.1.1
    wefwf_wewg.wegw.1.1
    434ssg.wegew.1.1
    wgw121.wefw.1.1
    wefew.sgw.341.5335
```

`{string or digits }.{string}.{digits}.{digits}` this will be the format but my regular expression is not working on **SQL Server**

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support Regex, that's why. If you *need* Regex support you'll need to look into CLR functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a real pain to express in SQL Server, but it is possible:

```
where name like '%.%.%.%' and
      name not like '%.%.%.%.%' and
      name not like '%[^.0-9a-zA-Z]%' and
      name not like '%.%[^0-9]%.%.%' and
      name not like '%.%.%[^a-zA-Z]%.%' and
      name not like '%.%.%.%[^a-zA-Z]%'
```

These implement the logic as:

- Has three periods.
- Does not have four.
- Has only dots, digits, and letters.
- Second component has no digits.
- Third component has no letters.
- Fourth component has no letters